# The usage of "Despite the fact that"

Tags: grammar, british-english

Can I add "such as " in front of the clause like this:

> Despite the fact that cognition may affect many different facets of ecology  in wild animals, such as, dominance, sexual selection and dispersal, the pathways via which cognition is translated into reproductive success are poorly understood.

Comment: You can't put a comma after "such as" like that.

Comment: Remove the comma between "such as" and "dominance."  As it stands, "wild animals," "such as," "dominance," "sexual selection," and "dispersal" all seem to be objects of the preposition "in," which is nonsense.

Comment: "Although" is generally preferable to "Despite the fact that." Further economy could be realized by reducing *ecology biology* to just *ecology.*

Comment: @ab2 I just want to say ecology.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The sentence reads fine, but please remove the commas before and after "such us". On the other hand, the sentence is long and has several clauses making the parsing hard, especially for non-natives. Unless you want to impress others with your elegant, long sentence you may want to reword it.

How about the following:

Cognition may affect many different facets of ecology biology in wild animals such as dominance, sexual selection and dispersal. However, the pathways via which cognition is translated into reproductive success are poorly understood.

Comment: What is ecology biology?